# How to stop the Tomcat 6.0 server

Tags: tomcat

How to stop the Tomcat 6.0 server ?

Under bin direcctory it has got only 4 files namely

bootstrap,  tomcat6 , tomcat6w , tomcat-juli

Under  TaskManager also , Windows Processes also , there is nothing related to tomcat

How can we stop the server instance now (I need to stop it as i modified some web.xml file )

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you started it.

If you started it by `startup.bat`, just use `shutdown.bat` which reside in the very same folder.

If it's started as Windows service (why have you by the way installed it as a Windows service if your intent is apparently to develop with it, not to run in production?), then you should restart the Windows service by service manager (start > run > services.msc).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running tomcat as a service then you should go to control panel>service an dthen start/stop from there.
Otherwise, there should be  batch file called shutdown.bat in bin directory.

How did you start the tomcat btw?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat6w is a GUI application for monitoring and configuring Tomcat services.

Use it (it opens in the tasktray)

Answer (score 0):

If tomcat 6 on windows is started as a service with a diffeernt name, you have to copy tomcat6w.exe to servicenamew.exe.   Then it will find it.  Don't forget the w.  For example, i have a tomcat6 that runs as "talend_tac".  I had to copy tomcat6w to talend_tacw.exe, then it would control the service.